# How to scale a Path to the direction it is pointed towards

Tags: paperjs

In my demo. I'm able to create a few ellipses that overlay each other. Each ellipse is slightly rotated and when click should stretch outwards.

However, right now I'm using .scale(x,y) and the ellipses's height increases vertically.

I'm not sure how I would accomplish this type of effect using paper.js

DEMO
[Code Pen Demo](https://codepen.io/kneepham/pen/qVeJwG)

```js
 paper.install(window);
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

 window.onload = function() {
  paper.setup('myCanvas');

  var numberOfRings = 6,
   rings = [],
   size = [225,400],
   colors = ['black','green','orange','blue','yellow','grey'],
   max_frame = 50,
   negative_scale = 0.99,
   positive_scale = 1.01;

  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRings; i++)
  {
   var path = new Path.Ellipse({
       center:view.center,
       size: size,
       strokeColor: colors[i],
       strokeWidth :10
   });

   var rotate = 30*i +30;

   path.rotate(rotate);
   path.animation = false;
   path.rotateValue = rotate;

   path.animationStartFrame = 0;
   path.animationScale = positive_scale;
   path.smooth();
   path.animationIndex = i;

   path.onClick = function(event) {
    rings[this.animationIndex].animation = true;
   }

   rings.push(path);

  }

  view.onFrame = function(event) {

   for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRings; i++)
   {

    if (rings[i].animation == true){

     if (rings[i].animationStartFrame == 0)
     {
      rings[i].animationStartFrame = event.count;
     }

     if (rings[i].animationStartFrame > 0 && event.count < (rings[i].animationStartFrame + max_frame)){
          
      // TODO
      rings[i].scale(1,rings[i].animationScale);

     } else if ( event.count > (rings[i].animationStartFrame + max_frame)){
      rings[i].animation = false;
      rings[i].animationStartFrame = 0;

      if (rings[i].animationScale == negative_scale)
       rings[i].animationScale = positive_scale;
      else
       rings[i].animationScale = negative_scale;
     }
    }

   }
  }




 }
```

```css
canvas{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the *desired* effect?

Comment: When a ring is click. The ring should stretch out in the angle its facing.

Initial look - https://codepen.io/kneepham/pen/qVeJwG 
End look when all rings are click-
 https://codepen.io/kneepham/pen/PEwLgz 
I'm having issue figuring out how to increase the height.

Answer (score 0):

first for this kind of things i think its easier to use paper.js / items with the [`applyMatrix`](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#applymatrix) option set to `false` - this way transformations are not applied / baked into the item/children/paths but stay separate in the transformation and so can also get manipulated later in an absolute fashion..

additionally to get to your desired effect i used a trick: [`Group`](http://paperjs.org/reference/group/)
i encapsulate the ellipse path in an group. so i can rotate the group only.
the coordinate-system of the child is not modified - and i can manipulate the ellipses scaling as in its original coordinate-system / as it was not rotated..

i have made some other modifications based on your example - mainly so its easier to test in different canvas-sizes and with different numbers of ellipses.

i first tested / developed it [at sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) (i find it easier to test/debug it there)
and then converted it to fit the the `plain js` version here.

if you want to do more complex animations please checkout the great library [animatePaper.js](http://eartz.github.io/animatePaper.js/) - i used it heavily and loved to work with it :-)
it supports simple and more complex animations of attributes of paper-objects.

```js
paper.install(window);
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

window.onload = function() {
    paper.setup('myCanvas');
    var numberOfRings = 5;
    var rings = [];
    let view_max_length = Math.min(view.size.width, view.size.height);
    var ringStartSize = new Size(view_max_length * 0.4, view_max_length * 0.45);
    var ringTargetLength = view_max_length * 0.9;
    var scaleStepSize = 0.01;


    function createRing(index) {
        let path = new Path.Ellipse({
            center: view.center,
            size: ringStartSize,
            strokeColor: {
                hue: (360 / numberOfRings) * index,
                saturation: 1,
                brightness: 1
            },
            strokeWidth: 10,
            applyMatrix: false,
            strokeScaling: false,
        });

        // add custom properties
        path.animate = false;
        path.animationDirectionOut = true;
        path.animationIndex = index;

        path.onClick = function(event) {
            //console.log(this);
            this.animate = true;
        };

        let rotationgroup = new Group(path);
        rotationgroup.applyMatrix = false;
        let offsetAngle = (360 / 2) / numberOfRings;
        let rotate = offsetAngle * index;
        rotationgroup.pivot = path.bounds.center;
        rotationgroup.rotation = rotate;

        return path;
    }

    function init() {
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRings; i++) {
            rings.push(createRing(i));
        }
    }

    function animateRing(event, ring) {
        if (ring.animate) {
            let tempScaleStep = scaleStepSize;
            if (!ring.animationDirectionOut) {
                tempScaleStep = tempScaleStep * -1;
            }
            ring.scaling.y += tempScaleStep;

            // test if we have reached destination size.
            if (
                (ring.bounds.height >= ringTargetLength) ||
                (ring.bounds.height <= ringStartSize.height)
            ) {
                ring.animate = false;
                // change direction
                ring.animationDirectionOut = !ring.animationDirectionOut;
            }
        }
    }

    view.onFrame = function(event) {
        if (rings && (rings.length > 0)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRings; i++) {
                animateRing(event, rings[i]);
            }
        }
    };


    init();

}
```

```css
canvas {
  widht: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```